# SDImageCache set maxMemoryCost does not do anything. Memory keeps increasing

Tags: ios, memory, sdwebimage

I use SDImageCache to cache images from a table view, but when scrolling down the memory keeps increasing. So I checked the library and found property in SDImageCache.h to set maxMemoryCost and expecting cache will be deleted over this limit. 
But in my test, [SDImageCache sharedImageCache] does not delete anything. So this property is currently doing nothing.

App will eventually crash on huge memory size.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hello I was facing the same problem and was fixed adding this lines on my `AppDelegate` `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    SDWebImageDownloader.shared().shouldDecompressImages = false
    SDImageCache.shared().shouldDecompressImages = false
}
```

## Update

This should fix the issue, founded here https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage/issues/1544#issuecomment-423445538

```
SDImageCache.shared().config.maxCacheAge = 3600 * 24 * 7 //1 Week
        
SDImageCache.shared().maxMemoryCost = 1024 * 1024 * 20 //Aprox 20 images
        
//SDImageCache.shared().config.shouldCacheImagesInMemory = false //Default True => Store images in RAM cache for Fast performance
        
SDImageCache.shared().config.shouldDecompressImages = false
        
SDWebImageDownloader.shared().shouldDecompressImages = false
        
SDImageCache.shared().config.diskCacheReadingOptions = NSData.ReadingOptions.mappedIfSafe
```

Hope this helps you, let me know about

Comment: Thanks your reply Reinier. Could you explain what does this by setting it to false?

Comment: @Ning I found this solution in some other place, I don't remember but this solves my problem, my app memory was growing uncontrolled because the load of big image resources with SDWebImage and this code fix the problem, did solve your problem?

Comment: I saw the comment on SDImageCacheConfig.h, shouldDecompressImages is moved into config now. It helps to reduce a portion of the memory consumption.  [SDImageCache sharedImageCache] setMaxMemoryCost and setMaxMemoryCountLimit also helps. Thanks

Comment: I am glad that my answer helped you to figured out how to solve your problem, congrats

Comment: Has this helped anyone else, because for me adding the above two methods is heaping up memory more tremendously.

Answer (score 0):

For me, clearing the memory cache is fixing the issue.

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self clearImageCacheFromMemory];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    [self clearImageCacheFromMemory];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void)clearImageCacheFromMemory{
    SDImageCache *imageCache = [SDImageCache sharedImageCache];
    [imageCache clearMemory];
}
```